# transform collection into a list in blade

Tags: php, laravel, list, collections, laravel-blade

anyone know how i transform this into a list in blade

[{"applicant": "Juan"}, {"applicant": "Pedro"}]

something like:

-Juan

-Pedro

currently that collection is an item of an array
{{$ applicant [$ i]}} contains [{"applicant": "Juan"}, {"applicant": "Pedro"}]

blade file

```
                    <td>
                        {{$applicant[$i]}}
                    </td>
```

Controller

```
for ($i=0; $i <= 59; $i++) {
            $materias[$i]->name;
            $applicant[$i] = DB::table('projections')
            ->where('s1',$materias[$i]->name)
            ->orWhere('s2',$materias[$i]->name)
            ->orWhere('s3',$materias[$i]->name)
            ->orWhere('s4',$materias[$i]->name)
            ->orWhere('s5',$materias[$i]->name)
            ->orWhere('s6',$materias[$i]->name)
            ->orWhere('s7',$materias[$i]->name)
            ->orWhere('s8',$materias[$i]->name)
            ->select('applicant')->get();
        }
```

Result
[image whit the result of the view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xB0qv.jpg)

Comment: do a `@foreach($applicant[$i] as $name)`

Answer (score 0):

In your Blade you need to make something like that :

[Check this documentation about loop in blade](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/blade#loops)

```
<td>
  <ul>
    @foreach($applicant[$i] as $appli)
      <li> {{ $appli }} </li>
    @endforeach
  </ul>
</td>
```